# Freemarker returns a null when using ?eval on string variable

Tags: java, freemarker

When using <#assing> in Freemarker it works if I just reference the variable but on using ?eval I am getting a null or missing error.

This works and newOwnerName gets the input value

`<#assign newOwnerName = jsonEventData.newOwnerName>`

But this does not work and results in an exception:

`<#assign newOwnerName = jsonEventData.newOwnerName?eval>`

Exception:

`The following has evaluated to null or missing: jsonEventData.newOwnerName?eval`

The reason I am trying to use ?eval is because the output includes quotes: The new owner name is "Peter". But I want it to be without quotes: The new owner name is Peter

The ftl template is something like:

```
<#assign newOwnerName = jsonEventData.newOwnerName>
The new owner name is ${newOwnerName}
```

I would expect that ?eval should not result in a null or missing error as the value is sent in the input

Comment: I tried your code in an [online parser](https://try.freemarker.apache.org/) with `jsonEventData_newOwnerName = "\"Peter\""` (replace **dot** by **underscore** for flat storage) and it outputs `The new owner name is Peter`. `?eval` correctly removes quotes. Check the contents of `jsonEventData.newOwnerName` again - something is missing.

Comment: Working Data: newOwnerName = "Peter". Template: <#assign newOwnerName = newOwnerName>
The new owner name is ${newOwnerName} Not working Data: newOwnerName = "Peter" Template: <#assign newOwnerName = newOwnerName?eval>
The new owner name is ${newOwnerName} @youka

Answer (score 1):

You can't `?eval` a string value without surrounding quotes in its content. `Peter` isn't a Freemarker variable. If your java input occasionally has or hasn't quotes this error is to expect. A cleaner solution would be detecting and removing quotes (substring) on java side.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [replace](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_string.html#ref_builtin_replace) freemarker's builtin to remove double quotes:

```
jsonEventData_newOwnerName?replace("\"","")
```

> used to replace all occurrences of a string in the original string with another string. It does not deal with word boundaries. For example: